# TypeORM: QueryFailedError when using raw SQL With PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I ran through the the TypeORM quickstart available on NPM at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm

I added a bit of code to experiment with raw SQL queries, but I'm immediately getting a QueryFailedError.

#### I'm curious how I can use raw SQL for the example below?

I verified that the table and entity were created by using TypeORM's connection.manager's find method, and I also manually inspected the table via pgAdmin. For good measure, I used pgAdmin to generate the intial SQL, which I then minimally modified.

I also verified that synchronize is set to true in the ormconfig.json file.

#### index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./entity/User";

createConnection().then(async connection => {
    const user = new User();
    user.firstName = "Timber";
    user.lastName = "Saw";
    user.age = 25;
    await connection.manager.save(user);

    let data = await connection.query(
        `SELECT firstName FROM public.user;`
    );
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

#### Error from stack trace and error info:

```
QueryFailedError: column "firstname" does not exist
...
message: 'column "firstname" does not exist',
name: 'QueryFailedError',
length: 108,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42703',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: '8',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'parse_relation.c',
line: '3293',
routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
query: 'SELECT firstName FROM user;',
```

Comment: Executive Summary: identifiers (table names, column names, ...) are folded to lower case unless they're double quoted, you want to say `SELECT "firstName" FROM user`.

Comment: it should work if you double quote your columns and single quote your values. E.g. `SELECT "firstName" from "public"."user";`